# Adding a random entry to an array

Tags: navigation, variable, array, random

I have a navi on which one entry consists of a random channel entry from one section among standard singles:

- Single 1
- Single 2
- Random Channel entry
- Single 3

I thought about something like this:

```
{% set randEntry = craft.entries.section('channelX').order('RAND()').first() %}
{% for navi in craft.entries.section(['single1', 'single2', randPortrait]) %}
  <li>{{ navi.title }}</li>
{% endfor %}
```

This does not work. (no error, but the variable is simply ignored).

I found a solution to pass in the variable when looping trough the array

```
{% set randEntry = craft.entries.section('channelX').order('RAND()').first() %}
{% for navi in craft.entries.section(['single1', 'single2', randPortrait]) %}
  <li>{{ navi.title }}</li>
  {% if loop.index == '2' %}
    <li>{{ randEntry.title }}</li>
  {% endif %}
{% endfor %}
```

But that's ugly. Is it possible to pass the whole thing into one array without conditional trickery?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `slice` and `merge` filters to “insert” that random entry into your array of entries.

In the following example I’m using the `id` param to query for the selected entries and I’m also setting `fixedOrder`, as this returns the entries in the same order as the IDs entered into the `id` param.

```
{% set selectEntries = craft.entries.id('7, 2, 83, 9, 90').fixedOrder(true) %}
{% set randEntry = craft.entries.section('channelX').order('RAND()').first() %}

{% set navEntries = selectEntries[:2]|merge([randEntry])|merge(selectEntries[2:]) %}
```